# Does Racquetball have a stand your ground rule?

Tags: rules, racquetball

A friend just explained the 'stand your ground' rule in handball where, on hitting the ball, you are allowed to stand where you are and have no obligation to get out of the way of your opponent.  He said it was the same in racquetball but I'm pretty sure you actually are obligated to get out of the way if needed.  The official rules seemed to support my understanding but it's not clear enough.  Which is correct?

Comment: What version of handball is that?  Hinder rules vary, and official rules describe situations where you must get out of the way, similar to how it is in racquetball.

Answer (score 1):

[Rule 3.15](http://www.internationalracquetball.com/media/2850/irf%20booklet%20V06_041613.pdf) of the [International Racquetball Federation](http://www.internationalracquetball.com/) states that "avoidable hinders", which result in loss of the rally, include:

> (a) Failure to move. A player does not move suﬃciently to allow an
>   opponent a shot straight to the front wall as well as a cross-court
>   shot [...]

This suggests to my mind that you must move out of the way of your opponent if it is necessary to do so to allow them to play their shot.